# Excel/Google Sheets SUMIF based on headers from multiple tables

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following:

[image: datasheet]

Each table represents a game (in this case of CS:GO).
What I want to do is get the sum of all kills, by all players, for each map, like:

```
Train: 208
Mirage: 103
```

I'm having some trouble with discriminating for each map. I can either do this in Google Sheets or in Excel.

Comment: The easiest is to add a new column that is linked to the main cell that list the Map.  Then a standard SUMIF will do it.  Outside of that, are there always 5 players?

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, B:B), 
 "Map", "♦"), "♦")), " ")), 
 "select Col1, Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6+Col7"), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you are assuming that there will always be 5 players, no more and no less?

Comment: There are always 5, not necessarily the same 5 though

Comment: @ScottCraner yes indeed

Comment: @player0 Might I ask how you came up with this or some pointers as to where I could learn it? I only now the basic of Google Sheets Query

Comment: @TiagoGrosso with luck :D not sure what exactly you asking about. I have no guides or anything. Just trying different stuff until I crack it

Comment: @TiagoGrosso let me know if you need formula breakdown